# Why Bind a socket

Tags: java, sockets

I've searched here and found a similar article but I didn't really get the answer I'm looking for. I'm learning Networking with Java through some examples and some pseudo-reverse engineering. Oracle's documentation is helping quite a bit too but I've got a few questions.

Why exactly do you bind an IP address to a `Socket`? Is it necessary? When would you use said binding?

Here is part of the code that raised the question to me:

```
ServerSocket myServerSocket = new ServerSocket(1337);
System.out.println("Server is waiting for an incoming connection from client...");
Socket recievingSocket = myServerSocket.accept();
```

Now from what I understand that if I was to bind a Socket it would be right after the running `accept()` correct?

Comment: A socket is, by definition, an IP address and a port.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152457/what-is-the-difference-between-a-port-and-a-socket

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003878/books-recommendation-to-learn-about-java-networking.  You may find it useful to read some good books

Comment: Well those two things are really the same thing. The address:port combination is normally only available to one socket.

Comment: Thank you all. This has been most informative! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why exactly do you bind an IP address to a Socket?

To determine which outbound interface it will connect via.

> Is it necessary?

In theory, no. In practice it is sometimes required when connecting via a VPN.

> Now from what I understand that if I was to bind a Socket it would be right after the running accept() correct?

Incorrect. An accepted or connected `Socket` is already bound. The only ways to bind a `Socket` are:

1. Create it with `new Socket()` with no arguments and then call `bind(),` or
2. Create it with the four-argument constructor, where the first two arguments are the target address and the second two are the bind-address.

The major use of `bind()` is in conjunction with `ServerSocket`. For instance, in your example, calling `new ServerSocket(1337)` creates a socket, binds it to 0.0.0.0:1337, and puts it into the LISTEN state.

Comment: So in the case of the Server bind() is essentially built into the constructor? I mean lets say I use a constructor without arguments (Assuming there is one defined) I would have to call bind() in that case yes?

Answer (score 0):

You bind a socket to an address in order to restrict where the socket is going to be listening to. It is not necessary if you want it to use default behavior, which IIRC is to listen to ANY.

You would bind before you use accept because accept tells the socket to start listening on the socket, but bind tell it where to look. The socket needs to know where to look before it listens.

Answer (score 0):

**Socket is essentially =  IP + Port.**

So yes you need an IP address to create a socket. And the process is termed as binding because you may bind multiple ports to same address all listening to their respective incoming connections.

Above pretty much sums your question of is it necessary but to add another point - Lets say you create a client to connect to your server. How will it connect if does not know server IP address and port to which it is suppose to connect.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, any of them, and the part starting 'the process is termed as binding' is basically meaningless.